# Edit python script in Power Bi

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, powerbi

I have ran a python script in Power Bi but now I want to open the script again and edit it.

Is there a way to open the script in PowerBI rather than copying and pasting the whole script from Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

In `Options - Global - Python scripting` you can set your *Python IDE* or any editor you like using the second dropdown menu.